# SCons AutoConfigBuilder

Tags: scons

I'm trying to get [`AutoConfigBuilder`](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/AutoConfigBuilder) working, but I'm having no luck.  I'm using SCons v2.3.4.

My SConstruct:

```python
env = Environment(tools = ['default','UnTar','AutoConfig'])
configured = env.AutoConfig('libpcap-1.6.2')
```

Output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
TypeError: Tried to lookup Dir 'libpcap-1.6.2' as a File.:
  File "/home/jreinhart/git_repos/scons-test/autoconf_builder/SConstruct", line 4:
    configured = env.AutoConfig('libpcap-1.6.2')
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 260:
    return MethodWrapper.__call__(self, target, source, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 224:
    return self.method(*nargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Builder.py", line 633:
    return self._execute(env, target, source, OverrideWarner(kw), ekw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Builder.py", line 554:
    tlist, slist = self._create_nodes(env, target, source)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Builder.py", line 484:
    slist = env.arg2nodes(source, source_factory)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 486:
    v = node_factory(self.subst(v, **kw))
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/FS.py", line 1340:
    return self._lookup(name, directory, File, create)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/FS.py", line 1319:
    return root._lookup_abs(p, fsclass, create)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/FS.py", line 2224:
    result.must_be_same(klass)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/FS.py", line 627:
    (self.__class__.__name__, self.path, klass.__name__))
```

Any advice on how to start working on this recipe? I'm not even sure what exactly is failing here. I'm assuming for some reason SCons thinks that when I call the builder like `env.AutoConfig('libpcap-1.6.2')`, that I'm referring to a file, not a directory.

I've posted this to the [scons mailing list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.tools.scons.user/26534/match=autoconfig), but I'd imagine Stack Overflow gets more traffic.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could find this is a bug in SCons itself. I'm not sure if/when it'll be fixed.

This is my workaround: force the parameter to be a SCons Dir object because SCons isn't getting it right.

Try this:

```
env.AutoConfig(env.Dir('libpcap-1.6.2'))
```